# Renouncing the devil during baptism

Tags: catholicism, baptism, satan, ambrose

In "On the Mysteries" (*De Mysteriis*) [[English](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf210.iv.v.iii.html)], Chapter 2, St. Ambrose wrote,

> After this the Holy of holies was opened to you, you entered the sanctuary of regeneration; recall what you were asked, and remember what you answered. **You renounced the devil and his works**, the world with its luxury and pleasures. That utterance of yours is preserved not in the tombs of the dead, but in the book of the living.
>
> *Post haec reserata tibi sunt sancta sanctorum, ingressus es regenerationis sacrarium: repete quid interrogatus sis, recognosce quid responderis. **Renuntiasti diabolo et operibus ejus**, mundo et luxuriae ejus ac voluptatibus. Tenetur vox tua, non in tumulo mortuorum, sed in libro viventium.*

In the Roman rite of the Catholic Church, does the individual **explicitly** "renounce the devil and his works" when he makes his confession of faith during baptism?

1. What was the formal statement made by the person being baptized?
2. If this statement is no longer made, when did the practice cease?

Comment: cf. [here](http://www.sanctamissa.org/en/resources/books-1962/rituale-romanum/12-baptism-of-adults-rite.html) and [here](http://www.ibreviary.com/m/preghiere.php?tipo=Rito&id=103). Perhaps you confused the Catholic Church with the Church of England ([renouncing the devil part will be optional](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS569US569&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=church+of+england+and+no+devil+in+baptism)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renunciation of the Devil in the Baptismal Rite is believed to be of Apostolic origin. The first explicit record of the use of this formula comes from Tertullian, where he says:

> "When we are going to enter the water, but a little before, in the presence of the congregation and under the hand of the president, we solemnly profess that we disown the devil, and his pomp, and his angels" - [De corona, iii.](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf03.iv.vi.iii.html)

**In the Roman rite of the Catholic Church, does the individual explicitly "renounce the devil and his works" when he makes his confession of faith during baptism?**

Yes.

**What was the formal statement made by the person being baptized?**

It is done in one of the following manner during the baptismal rite of an Infant: (src: [Rite for the Baptism of One Child](http://www.catholicliturgy.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/textcontents/index/4/subindex/67/textindex/7))

> The celebrant questions the parents and godparents:
>
> A.
>
> Celebrant: Do you reject Satan?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.
>
> Celebrant: And all his works?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.
>
> Celebrant: And all his empty promises?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.
>
> **Or** B.
>
> Celebrant: Do you reject sin, so as to live in the freedom of God′s
>   children?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.
>
> Celebrant: Do you reject the glamor of evil, and refuse to be mastered
>   by sin?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.
>
> Celebrant: Do you reject Satan, father of sin and prince of darkness?
>
> Parents and Godparents: I do.

During adult baptism, same question is asked directly to the person (src: [Rite for baptism of adults](http://www.sanctamissa.org/en/resources/books-1962/rituale-romanum/12-baptism-of-adults-rite.html)). Note that during an infant baptism, the Parents and Godparents reply '***I*** do'. They are responding in the place of the Child. This rite is repeated on every Easter vigil too.

**If this statement is no longer made, when did the practice cease?**

As far as I know, this practice has not ceased.

Comment: Only one thing to improve the answer: even though you link to the source, it would be more complete to actually name the source in  your text.

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach**

During *the Liturgy of Easter Sunday of the Resurrection of the LORD* there is the RENEWAL OF BAPTISMAL PROMISES. Quoting from [the DAILY ROMAN MISSAL According to the *Roman Missal, Third Edition*](https://www.scepterpublishers.org/product/index.php?FULL=684) *(my emphasis)*:

> 55. *When the Rite of Baptism (and Confirmation) has been completed or, if this has not taken place, after the blessing of water, all
>       stand, holding lighted candles in their hands, **and renew the promise
>       of baptismal faith**, unless this has already been done together with
>       those to be baptized (cf. no. 49)*
>
> *The priest addresses the faithful in these or similar words.*
>
> Dear brethren (brothers and sisters), through the Paschal Mystery we
>   have been buried with Christ in Baptism, so that we may walk with him
>   in newness of life. And so, now that our Lenten observance is
>   concluded, **let us renew the promises of Holy Baptism, by which we
>   once renounced Satan and his works** and promised to serve God in the
>   holy Catholic Church.
>
> And so I ask you:
>
> **Priest: Do you renounce Satan?
>
>   All: I do.**
>
> Priest: And all his works?
>   All: I do.
>
> Priest: And all his empty show?
>   All: I do.
>
> OR:
>
> Priest: Do you renounce sin, so as to live in the freedom of the
>   children of God?
>   All: I do.
>
> Priest: Do you renounce the lure of evil, so that sin may have no
>   mastery over you?
>   All: I do.
>
> **Priest: Do you renounce Satan, the author and prince of sin?
>
>   All: I do.**
>
> [...]

---

***Answering***

From this yearly *renewal of baptismal promises* the faithful **renew the promises of Holy Baptism, by which they once renounced Satan**.

The wording in this renewal is the same as that one at Baptism and it has not changed. If it changed, one would be unable to renew.